Text.Pandoc.Writers.Markdown does not include YAML, despite option set
I try to reproduce a markdown file after having read it using the markdown writer. I have tested that
`pandoc -s -t markdown input.md -o output.md` 

produces a file with the YAML header. In the source code I see that an extension Ext_yaml_metadata_block must be set.
Unfortunately, in my Haskell code, the writer produces only the content, but not the YAML header, despite the fact that I set the extension in reading and writing. What is additionally required or whatelse is wrong in my code? Thank you for help!
My minimal but not very realistic MWE:
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}

module MarkdownYAMLquestion where

import qualified Text.Pandoc as Pandoc
import           Text.Pandoc.Definition as Pandoc(Pandoc(..))
import           Uniform.PandocImports(unPandocM) 
import           UniformBase(s2t,putIOwords, runErr, ErrIO, Text, showT)
 
 
smallMD :: Text 
smallMD = s2t $ unlines 
    ["---"
    , "keywords: somewords"
    , "showframe: False"
    , "---"
    , ""
    , "some content text"
    ]
testyaml :: IO ()
-- a minimal example 
testyaml = do 
    res <- runErr $ do 
        pan1 <- readMarkdown3 smallMD
        putIOwords ["the pandoc", showT pan1] -- the YAML header is parsed!
        mdRes <- writeToMarkdown3 pan1 
        putIOwords ["\n\nthe file reproduced\n", mdRes]
    putIOwords ["testyaml end res", showT res]


writeToMarkdown3 :: Pandoc -> ErrIO Text
-- write with yaml header
writeToMarkdown3  pan1= unPandocM $ Pandoc.writeMarkdown 
                            markdownWriterOptionsx pan1

markdownWriterOptionsx :: Pandoc.WriterOptions
markdownWriterOptionsx = Pandoc.def {Pandoc.writerExtensions = exts}
    where
        exts = mconcat [ Pandoc.extensionsFromList
                            [Pandoc.Ext_yaml_metadata_block]
                            ]

readMarkdown3 ::  Text ->   ErrIO Pandoc
-- | reads the markdown text and produces a pandoc structure
-- the filename is only used for the error message
readMarkdown3 text1 = unPandocM  $ Pandoc.readMarkdown markdownOptions text1

markdownOptions :: Pandoc.ReaderOptions
markdownOptions = Pandoc.def { Pandoc.readerExtensions = exts }
  where
    exts = mconcat
        [ Pandoc.extensionsFromList
            [ Pandoc.Ext_yaml_metadata_block
            -- , Pandoc.Ext_fenced_code-block -- code blocks with ~
            , Pandoc.Ext_backtick_code_blocks
            , Pandoc.Ext_fenced_code_attributes  -- eg for haskell code snippets
            , Pandoc.Ext_auto_identifiers
            -- , Pandoc.Ext_raw_html   -- three extension give markdown_strict
            , Pandoc.Ext_raw_tex   --Allow raw TeX (other than math)
            , Pandoc.Ext_latex_macros -- allow tex for math
            , Pandoc.Ext_tex_math_dollars 
            , Pandoc.Ext_shortcut_reference_links
            , Pandoc.Ext_spaced_reference_links
            , Pandoc.Ext_footnotes  -- all footnotes
            , Pandoc.Ext_inline_notes
            , Pandoc.Ext_citations           -- <-- this is the important extension for bibTex
            , Pandoc.Ext_implicit_figures  -- a figure alone in a para will have a caption
            , Pandoc.Ext_header_attributes -- for {.unnumbered}
            , Pandoc.Ext_lists_without_preceding_blankline
            , Pandoc.Ext_superscript  -- start and closing ^
            , Pandoc.Ext_subscript -- start and closing ~
            -- , Pandoc.Ext_short_subsuperscripts  -- only start ^ and ~
            , Pandoc.Ext_strikeout  -- require ~~ two! before and after
            , Pandoc.Ext_smart -- Smart quotes, apostrophes, ellipses, dashes
            ]
        , Pandoc.githubMarkdownExtensions
        ]


Given I understand it correctly, that is the Meta from the Pandoc object.

@willeM_VanOnsem - if 'that' refers to pan1: pan is the result of the read with type Pandoc, i.e a Meta and a [Block]. The same type as requires as input to the writeMarkdown.(unPandocis just a conversion from thePandocMonadto theErrIOmonad, which is anEither` type to merge error and result.)

I think what willeM tried to say is that the yaml you're looking for is in the Meta field. Is your question how to turn that Meta into a YAML-formatted Text string, or...?

I try to reproduce the original md file as read. pandoc -t -s markdown file1.md -o file2.md does it properly, i.e. yaml and markdown text. i think a simple method to return the Meta field into a YAML-format would be a choice, requiring afterwards the combination. -- Staring at the pandocToMarkdown code in the Pandoc source, I have the impression that it uses a template, which I have not yet found.

The issue is with the markdownWriter (specifically with pandocToMarkdown in Text.Pandoc.Writers.Markdown) which requires the extension Pandoc.Ext_yaml_metadata_block and a writerTemplate, which must be downloaded and compiled first. The default markdown template can be compiled and then loaded into the writerTemplate option.
With this option and extension set, the markdown file with YAML block and content is properly reproduced. In the application the purpose of reading and writing is to change the meta data and thus have a YAML block with added default values.
The changes were all in the writeToMarkdown3 which replaces the code in the original question.
writeToMarkdown3 :: Pandoc -> ErrIO Text
-- write with yaml header
writeToMarkdown3    pan1 = do 
        template <- unPandocM $ getDefaultTemplate "markdown"
        compTpl :: (Template Text) <- unPandocM $ compileDefaultTemplate "markdown"       
        unPandocM $ Pandoc.writeMarkdown 
                            (markdownWriterOptions compTpl) pan1

markdownWriterOptions :: Template Text ->  Pandoc.WriterOptions
markdownWriterOptions  tpl  = 
        Pandoc.def {Pandoc.writerTemplate = (Just ( tpl) )
                    , Pandoc.writerExtensions = exts}
    where
        exts =    Pandoc.extensionsFromList
                            [Pandoc.Ext_yaml_metadata_block]

